# How to install Ubuntu on a NvMe Disk

Tags: dell, nvme

I have a DELL XPS with 2 NvMe Disks.
The installation does not see any of those NvME disk.
How to be able to see the NvMe Disks during initial installation?
I found somewhere "nvme_load=YES" but I do not know if it is correct, or how to add to the install command line.

Thank You

Comment: How far along does the installer get? Does it throw an error "Executing 'grub-install /dev/nvmeXXX' failed. This is a fatal error."?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware and SSD firmware? Most instructions say to change Intel RST or RAID to AHCI, not vice-versa as in answer below? https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571

Answer (score 1):

There is an article on DELL's website to solve this problem. I think the solution will take only a few minutes.

### Resolution

1. Boot your computer and access the BIOS.

On most Dell computers, you can rapidly tap the F2 key at the Dell Splash Screen to boot directly to the BIOS. Always follow the on-screen instructions.

2. Go to the SATA Operation category and select the RAID On option.
3. Save the changes and the computer will reboot.
4. Connect the Linux installation media and boot to it to start the operating system installation.

On most Dell computers, you can rapidly tap the F12 key at the Dell Splash Screen to boot to an on-screen boot menu. Use the cursor keys to select the correct option for your media type and hit Enter.

5. Follow the steps in the How to Install Ubuntu Linux on your Dell PC article to complete the installation.

### Reference

- https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/tr-tr/000132047/how-to-resolve-an-pcie-nvme-m-2-ssd-ubuntu-kubuntu-installation-problem-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en